# Frequency progressive signals vs time progressive signals?

Tags: communication, seti

I am not very experienced with signals, but something that has occurred to me while reading on various ways we are searching for ET signals, is that it seems most people rule out a signal unless it's in a narrow band. Is there any literature about treating signals that span a broad range of frequencies? This came from thinking that perhaps instead of utilizing a narrow band to send out a message, perhaps a theoretical ET might send their messages back and forth in a single burst, where the data, instead of "progressing" by time, progresses by frequency.

Possibility or gross concept error?

Who has attempted looking signals in this manner?

Comment: Where did you read that signals not in a narrow band are excluded?

Comment: I get the impression that SETI et al look for carrier waves, not data (because data quickly becomes unreadable at interstellar distances). From Earth, the signals that are identifiable from furthest away are radar transmissions, not radio/TV.

Comment: @Schusstein: Quite a few places. An example: http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/131-observational-astronomy/seti-and-extraterrestrial-life/seti/796-why-does-the-seti-project-search-for-radio-signals-intermediate

Comment: @Hobbes While getting an example for Schlusstein, I found a partial answer to my question that agrees with portions of what you mentioned. [edit-adding due to typo] I see now some reasons why we narrow our search. To clarify: again I am not a signals or communications expert, and I now see potential for mis-understanding. Let me clarify: I do not mean "narrow band" in conventional terms **necessarily**. It occurred to me that since the **entire** electromagnetic band is analogue (at least more or less, to my knowledge). This might allow a sophisticated communication system to send (continued)

Comment: A nearly infinite amount of data in a single pulse lasting a fraction of a second, by using a signal by our measurements that is ultra strong, and the data is carried in the amplitude of a pulse spanning many frequencies. With the knowledge I have recently gained, it seems this kind of signal would have portions of it lost to us due to space particles, but I still am wondering... perhaps large pulses that span various portions of the electromagnetic spectrum that we catch could be partial messages by an ETI communicating with itself. Plausible possibility? Or gross concept error?

Comment: "Ultra strong" I would define as being economically strong enough for their technology to detect the difference in ampltiutide between their own signals and background signals, which to us could potentially look like something not quite as strong as the background noise around them. This is making the assumption the the signal for ETI to ETI was intended for a relatively short hmrange AKA: between a few or a few hundred light years instead of across the entire galaxy. They could interpret the signal easily without any guesswork, but any listener beyond their scope would receive (continued)

Comment: A portion of the message inversely relates to their (our) distance from them). I am basing this on the assumption that we are not special, thus if we have not "seen" anything, it's probably because we just haven't learned how to look.

Comment: The technique you're referring to is known as 'spread spectrum' and is used on Earth e.g. by the military, because it's difficult to detect that a transmission is taking place, let alone decode it. That makes it not a good candidate for SETI.

Comment: @Hobbes Gave me some good answers to the first portion of my question, thank you!

Comment: I think this is an extremely interesting question! WiFi, Bluetooth, cell phones, GPS, we use various kinds of spread spectrum modulation all the time. In many cases, *if the signal is weak* you might not even know it's there if you aren't correlating with the right code at the proper rate. That might be the basis of at least a partial answer. I don't know enough about SETI detection algorithms to know if they look for more than elevated levels in statically defined frequency slots or not.

Comment: For anyone interested, thanks to @Hobbes for pointing me towards spread spectrum, I found an article that describes what I was thinking. It points out how we generally search for signals, as well as describes some really good reasons why spread spectrum might be used by a theoretical ETI. Not for the same reasons I was thinking though (the potential to transmit a near-infinite amount of data in a fraction of a second). Article: http://www.centauri-dreams.org/?p=22025

Comment: @Hobbes one way to look at this is the "dropped keys" scenario - looking under a streetlight rather than next to one's car where keys were dropped because it is dark where the car is. Yes it's much harder, but...